# How to carve a hollow cylinder along the curved surface in Fusion 360

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

Let me start with a disclaimer: I'm new to 3D design, to design in general and specifically brand new to Fusion 360. This is my first project.

I started by creating a hollow cylinder, with the one end open and the other end closed. For example a hollow cylinder with the bottom closed and the top open.

I was able to create such hollow cylinder using the cylinder and shell tools.

Now, I wish to carve / engrave a pattern on the shell. I may want this carving to go all the way through the shell (practically making a hole the shape of my pattern); or,I may just want to engrave on part of the shell, but not cut all the way though.

My pattern is a sound wave. I have a 2D black and white image of this sound wave. I may want to carve it onto the curved shell, so that it curves around the cylinder.

I hope my description is clear. Another way to describe what I'm looking for, is to imagine cutting the sound wave pattern though a 2D rectangle, and then curl this rectangle along its width into a cylinder.

How can I do something like that?

Comment: I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEdbBTQ0qaw) from a quick search, but it only seems to show how to lay a 2d image onto a 3D surface from *one* direction. Could it perhaps be useful for you too? :-)

Comment: A couple a limitations of the technique @TormodHaugene described.  1) It requires a vector (svg) image - you cannot use a bitmap/raster image (like bmp or jpg) 2) It etches the lines vertically (not perpendicular to the surface).  It may be possible to use the technique to etch a flat plate that you then bend to a cylinder so the resulting etch would be perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Until recently, this was not possible with Fusion 360. If you have a flat sketch, operations such as extrude can only linearly project it to a curved surface, and not wrap it around. However, I have seen mention where people have been able to trick the new sheetmetal features to accomplish a wrapped shape, then join to other objects. This tutorial may help. I have not tried this myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be engraved, then sketch out the sound wave on the center plane. When you go to extrude, click "extrude from", and then click "from object". Click on the plane you want to extrude from, and then 2xtrude however for you would like to. Another way to do this would be to project the sketch onto the surface, and then extrude the projection.